# How would I put a shadowblur on a single layer in Deck.gl?

Tags: javascript, deck.gl

I'm using Deck.gl for a 2d visualization (not a map) that utilizes multiple layers:
`[SolidPolygonLayer, ScatterplotLayer, LineLayer]`
I would like to apply a shadowblur effect to only the LineLayer. Is that possible?

So far, I've looked at the `PostProcessEffect` module, but I think it effects all visible layers.